# JUnit test hangs

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

I have the following problem: one of my JUnit tests gets stuck in eclipse doing nothing, but the blue arrow indicating that this test is currently running persists.

There definitely isn't any infinite loop in my code, and everything in the tested method that gets stuck is in the following `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.length(); i += 3) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Also, when debugging, the method properly terminates and does not let me step any more.

In the `setUp()` I am initializing my fields and the class under test.

This seems like some weird JUnit/Eclipse bug.
I am running Eclipse 3.7.2 and JUnit 4 under Ubuntu 12.04 using oracle-java-7.

Any tips how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: what is your implementation of `length()`?

Comment: how big is the result of `length()?` are you doing something to `i` in your loop?

Comment: If the test is still running, you can look at the active threads in the `debug` tab and suspend them by pressing the pause button. That will tell you where the test is stuck. Your question also needs more context for us to help you.

Comment: Cant post the my code, but the class is a linked list implementation, the length method is definitely working as intended. length() = 5 in the test. Yes, im using the counter to iterate over the list and getting elements through i.

Comment: -1 for gross lack of information.  It could be hanging on IO, you don't say whether it is doing any.  If there are other threads, that might explain why stepping through it works but running it does not.  I'm suspicious of an endless loop, mostly because you say "definitely no".  You don't say whether you've put trace statements in the code to help determine what it is doing, possibly because you are convinced it is "doing nothing".  You haven't even given us enough information to offer "tips how to troubleshoot".

Comment: @DeepakBala This helped. I found my mistake through this. Its another method that is doing weird things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MaxNi Glad to help. I'll move my comment to the answers section.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the test is still running, you can look at the active threads in the `debug` tab and suspend them by pressing the pause button. That will tell you where the test is stuck.

Comment: For this to work you must have started the tests in debug mode.